# Autocomplete parentheses when editing lisp

Tags: auto-complete-mode

I am learning Lisp and find out that autocomplete parentheses is counter intuitive. I don't like it because I don't know how many parenthesis will go into another at the first hand. For example,

```
(defun last-elt (list)
  (let* ((len (length list))
         (last (nth len list)))
    (break)
    last))
```

that code is hard to type for me using auto-complete parentheses. How do experienced lisp programmers use auto-complete property?

Comment: Too broad (how do you use auto-complete?). FWIW, I don't autocomplete 
 or auto-insert paired parentheses. I do use `show-paren-mode` and a non-`nil` option `blink-matching-paren`.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out which tools lisp programmers use. I am using electric-pair-mode to pair parenthesis. But Lisp programming with so many parenthesis, it is difficult to use it. Maybe I am beginner and I don't see beforehand how many parenthesis I will need for the function definition.

Comment: Please explain why "that code is hard to type for me using auto-complete parentheses".  I don't know how you type it nor at which step you encounter difficulties.

Comment: This sounds weird to me: "I don't see beforehand how many parenthesis I will need for the function definition." Why do you need to know beforehand? When using `electric-pair-mode` you just type as you normally would, the same characters in exactly the same order. The only difference is that typing the left parenthesis inserts both the left and the right parenthesis, and typing the right parenthesis just skips over the previously inserted right parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're editing *lines of code* instead of *S-expressions*.  As long as you think of Lisp as lines of code, things like electric-pair-mode are going to drive you nuts.

First off:

When using something like electric-pair-mode, you never, *never*, **never** delete a parenthesis using something like delete, backspace, or line-oriented commands.  Always use the S-expression commands for deletion, like C-M-k.

That's 90% of success with using automatic parentheses management.  The other 10% is mostly learning to ignore the parenthesis at the front of your cursor.

Secondly:

It is very helpful to use the native S-expression-based commands for navigation and editing.  Most of them are in the "Editing Programs" section of the manual.  Not only do these keep parentheses balanced (which keeps electric-pair-mode happy), but they're faster and they'll help you think of your code in terms of S-expressions instead of lines.

My advice:

Once you've gotten the hang of the basic S-expression commands and you've written enough Lisp code to feel comfortable, get something like paredit, lispy, or smartparens and learn the commands they give you.  These take the basic functionality of electric-pair-mode and add other conveniences on top of it.  I like paredit, personally, but to each their own.

Comment: It is intimating for a novice Lisp programmer seeing many parentheses at the front of my cursor. So I will learn them ignore it. Thanks